# FOSUserBundle - Overriding forms: could not load type "user_registration"

Tags: php, symfony

I created my own form type at `Me\MyBundle\Form\Type\UserFormRegistrationType`:

```
namespace Me\MyBundle\Form\Type;

use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserFormRegistrationType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        // all my unique fields
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_registration';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Me\MyBundle\Entity\User'));
    }
}
```

I have the following in my services.yml:

```
services:
    me_my.registration.form.type:
        class: Me\MyBundle\Form\Type\UserFormRegistrationType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: user_registration }
```

And the following added to my config.yml:

```
# other config stuff

fos_user:
    # database stuff, general config

    registration:
        form:
            type: user_registration
```

Yet, when I try to access my registration form/page, I get:

> Could not load type "user_registration"

Any hint to what I'm obviously missing?  It's not a firewall issue.  I had one, but tweaking my security.yml fixed it.  This is a pure not found error.  Very annoying, as I believe I followed the docs to the letter.

Comment: have you got your solution please share

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The docs declined to mention/remind that the service needs to be registered in config.yml.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use aliases anymore

In your config file :

Before : 

    `registration:
        form:
            type: user_registration`

New :

    `registration:
        form:
            type: 'CoreBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType'`

In your src/CoreBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php: getParent() function should be :

```
public function getParent()
{
    return "FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType";
}
```

Don't forget the use on the top of the file :

    `use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType;`

Hi here is the explanation : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53048060/7888453

Official : 
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this guys problem and then the solution that he provides to his own question. I went off of his code and modified it to match the names within my files and it worked!

[How to override register form FosUserBundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305417/how-to-override-register-form-fosuserbundle)