# How to override register form FosUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

I want to override some of FOSUserBundle forms ( registration form ) So I followed the documentation and I cant understand why I keep getting the same error :

> Attempted to load class "RegistrationFormType" from namespace
>   "OC\UserBundle\Form\Type". Did you forget a "use" statement for
>   "FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType"?
>        500 Internal Server Error - ClassNotFoundException.

These are my files:

RegistrationFormType.php:

```
<?php
namespace OC\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('telephone');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'oc_user_registration';
    }
}
```

Service.yml of the OCUserBundle:

```
services:
    oc_user_registration:
        class: OC\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - {name: form.type, alias: oc_user_registration}
```

and I configured the project to use my form type when the user tries to register in the app/Ressources/config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: OC\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: oc_user_registration
```

Please can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: `FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType` class cannot be found. Are you sure it is installed? Maybe you forgot to run `composer install`?

Comment: No. When I change the register form to use from "oc_user_registration" to "fos_user_registration" it works

Comment: Has your OC\UserBundle the FosUserBundle as a parent?

Comment: yes, I overrided the login form, it works like a charm but now I'm stuck here. This is my OCUserBundle.php :

    <?php

    namespace OC\UserBundle;

    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

    class OCUserBundle extends Bundle
    {
        public function getParent()
        {
            return 'FOSUserBundle';
        }
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this. The error was that the path to the path to the FormType file wasn't the same as the namespace. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You see https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

All is explain, I already use and is ok

Answer (score 0):

add his function to your registration form type

> public function getParent()
>       {
>           return 'fos_user_registration';
>       }

Comment: this can't be the problem. This is used just when you want to include predefined inputs of the fosuserbundle in my new registration form. Adding it didn't affect the error I get.