# FOSUserBundle overwrite registration but Could not load type error

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I tried to use the FOSUserBundle, I followed the instructions on the documentation for overwriting the Bundle, but I get this error when I try to access to /register while /login works (I didn't overwrite it):

```
Could not load type "app_user_registration"
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

**Configurations**

Symfony version: *3.1.7*

FOSUserBundle version: *dev-master*

**My files**

app/config/services.yml:

```
services:
    app.form.registration:
        class: CoreBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

app/config/config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: CoreBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: app_user_registration
```

src/CoreBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php

```
<?php
// src/CoreBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php

namespace CoreBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
?>
```

src/viwa/UserBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php:

```
<?php
// src/viwa/UserBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php

namespace viwa\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    // Don't need to change this right now.
}
?>
```

src/viwa/UserBundle/viwaUserBundle.php:

```
<?php
// src/viwa/UserBundle/viwaUserBundle.php

namespace viwa\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class viwaUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

If you need anything other to help me I edit my post.

Hope anyone can help me out.

Comment: In your config.yml, instead of using the alias app_user_resitration, use CoreBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType. getParent() in your CoreBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType should return ''FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType' . If I see more will comment again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your **config.yml** file should be:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: CoreBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: CoreBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
```

In your `src/CoreBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php`, `getParent()` function should be:

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! This solved my issue, but I don't understand why ? On the Symfony docs there is no namespace on these places

Answer (score 1):

You probably read documentation for '1.3.x / current' which is open by default.
If you switch to '2.0 / master' you will se the correct version of documentation.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but for future users who come here it might help if you include the solution for the problem in your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but as I found it searching for the same problem, I share my solution, like the accepted answer, but more conform to the suggested/official syntax :)
I have upgraded to symfony 3.4, and FosUserBundle 2.1, now you need to return the FQCN as explain in the [UPGRADE 2.x to 3.0](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form)

> Returning type instances from FormTypeInterface::getParent() is not
>   supported anymore. Return the fully-qualified class name of the parent
>   type class instead.
>
> Before:

```
class MyType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return new ParentType();
    }
}
```

> After:

```
class MyType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return ParentType::class;
    }
}
```

In this case:

```
public function getParent()
{
    return RegistrationFormType::class;
}
```

Don't forget the use on the top of the file:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType;
```